# Как после падения главного окна PyQt5 с ошибкой вызвать сообщение с текстом об ошибке?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qmessagebox, qdialog

У меня есть приложении на *PyQt5*, которое, предположим, может упасть после некоторой ошибки.

Как мне в коде из примера ниже добиться такого результата, чтобы после падения главного окна оно закрывалось и вызывалось небольшое диалоговое окно с текстом об ошибке и кнопкой "Ок", после закрытия которого приложение `app` завершало работу?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)

        self.btn_crash_programm = QPushButton('Crash')
        self.btn_crash_programm.clicked.connect(self.crash)
        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.btn_crash_programm)

    def crash(self):
        x = 2 / 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я планировал добиться этого, оборачивая эту часть кода в `try - except`, но это не работает, блок `except` не выполняется, главное окно закрывается, а приложение продолжает работать и грузить систему.

```
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, \
    QApplication, QPushButton, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_main_window)

        self.btn_crash_programm = QPushButton('Crash')
        self.btn_crash_programm.clicked.connect(self.crash)
        self.layout_main_window.addWidget(self.btn_crash_programm)

    def crash(self):
        x = 2 / 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import traceback                                                    # +++ 
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    def excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        tb = "".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb))
        
        msg = QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            "Error catched!:",
            tb
        )
        QApplication.quit()
    
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, работает!

Comment: @Etozeigor пожалуйста.